# Alternative to Thread.Sleep in windows Form apart from Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I am using Thread.Sleep in windows form C#. using which results in Not responding of Form.
Using Timer is also not serving my purpose.

**Sample Code:**

```
if(......)    // There are many if with difrent components and many Thread.sleep
{
      button.visible=true;
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      GotoMeasurementMode(3000);
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      query(device.Text);
      Thread.sleep(7000);
      StopMeasurement();
      Thread.sleep(4000);
 }
```

Using above Code results in form irresponsiveness. Using Timer gonna result in Nested Timers. and Not fessable in my case.
Please tell me an alternative in windows form. Want the specific pause between commands.

Comment: multi-threading, there isn't any other option

Comment: *Never* call Thread.Sleep() on the UI thread of a winforms program.  The UI goes to sleep.  Use a Timer instead.  Or a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I'd personally say never call `Thread.Sleep()`, period.  Its very existence inevitably causes more problems than it solves.  But that's an argument for another time.

Comment: @cHao I think it's valid to call `Thread.Sleep(0)` in some circumstances.

Comment: @cHao - please suggest your alternative for a five second delay in a function called from multiple threads, called from multiple places, and several levels down a call stack.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I'd consider even Thread.Sleep(0) a bit iffy, until/unless you are optimizing and know more about your threads' scheduling and dependencies than the OS does.

Comment: @MartinJames: There shouldn't *be* a five-second delay in such a function.

Comment: WHAT! The spec says 'wait for five seconds'.

Comment: @MartinJames: The spec is invalid.

Comment: @MartinJames: The only place where explicitly waiting for any amount of real-world time is acceptable is in the UI, where it'd be far better handled with a timer.

Comment: @MartinJames: If you are sleeping in some deeply nested part of the app, it's never for the right reason.  I repeat, *never* for the right reason.  You have an inherent race condition, because you're conflating real-world time and CPU time.  The only point of sleeping in such a situation *might* be in a test case where you're pretending to be doing some real work.  But in the app itself, never.  And the app itself should never *require* that wait anyway.

Comment: 'inherent race condition' - now you're trolling.

Comment: The spec says I have to wait.  'After turning on the pump, wait five seconds for the pressure to stabilize before opening the feed valve'.

Comment: @MartinJames: Better handled with a timer or async task.

Comment: But again...this is an argument for another time.

Comment: @cHao - OK :) filler...

Answer (score 13):

The easiest option is to use this model:

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        button.visible=true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        GotoMeasurementMode(3000);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        query(device.Text);
        await Task.Delay(7000);
        StopMeasurement();
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to C# 5.0 you can do this in 4.0.  You'll need to start with your own `Delay` method, as one doesn't exist in .NET 4.0:

```
public static Task Delay(int milliseconds)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(o => tcs.SetResult(false));
    timer.Change(milliseconds, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Using that we can now write:

```
Delay(1000)
    .ContinueWith(t => GotoMeasurementMode(3000), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
    .ContinueWith(t => Delay(3000)).Unwrap()
    .ContinueWith(t => query(device.Text), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
    .ContinueWith(t => Delay(7000)).Unwrap()
    .ContinueWith(t => StopMeasurement(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
    .ContinueWith(t => Delay(4000)).Unwrap();
```

That is pretty similar to the code that the first snippet will be compiled into, but clearly that first one is much prettier, so you should use it if at all possible.

If we go back to C# 3.0 then we lose access to the `Task`, this means that we're back to using timers and callbacks.  We'll start with this simple helper method to handle managing the task for us:

```
public static void ExecuteIn(int milliseconds, Action action)
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => { action(); timer.Stop(); };
    timer.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer.Start();
}
```

Then we can just nest calls to this:

```
ExecuteIn(1000, () =>
{
    GotoMeasurementMode(3000);
    ExecuteIn(3000, () =>
    {
        query(device.Text);
        ExecuteIn(7000, () => StopMeasurement());
    });
});
```

While it's possible to re-create a `Task` in C# 3.0 (it doesn't leverage any of the 4.0 language features) and there are existing libraries that do that, that would be somewhat more involved.

Comment: that would be ideal, but only available on .NET 4.5

Comment: Ok, if that does what it looks like it does, i'm gonna fall in love with C# all over again.

Comment: @JohnField Added a C# 4.0 solution in there as well.  It could also be modified easily enough to work in 3.0 or 2.0 if that were important, but it would involve a tad more work.

Comment: There's an easier solution for C# 4.0: add the NuGet package `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and then use `TaskEx.Delay` instead of `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Well, for me it's *easier* to just write/copy a four line method than to reference an additional assembly.  It may be a better idea though, particularly if you use it a lot as that implementation handles a few edge cases this doesn't.  If you're leveraging other functionality that is in the library then it's probably going to be easier.

Comment: @servy: in .NET 4.0 - wondering whether the `ContinueWith` stair-case is really useful. Yes, `ContinueWith` is non-blocking and scale-able and all that is true in general, however, I don't think that's a problem in this situation. no one is going to run 100 copies of the winform app at a go - nor does running anything in parallel seems to be the need. If new thread `Control.Invoke`/`thread.Sleep` is used, he's going to block at most one thread. Plus code is more readable and also you can put that stuff in single try/catch in case needed. Can you throw some light why `ContinueWith` is better?

Comment: @Servy: What I meant by "easier" was actually the `ContinueWith` vs `await`, particularly regarding execution context and exception handling.

Comment: @YK1 It's hard to say how much something like this will need to scale.  Also keep in mind it's not just this one place, it's any place where you need to delay execution of anything.  Readability is also subjective; riddling this type of code with calls to `Invoke` could be just as bad as what's here.  As for error handling; since all of the work appears to need to be done in the UI thead, you wouldn't be able to wrap code like this in a `try/catch` and have it handle that in *either* solution (although my first solution would handle it).

Comment: @StephenCleary Ah, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Servy: `it's any place where you need to delay` - yeah i understand, I was saying only in this particular scenario why would `ContinueWith` is better than Thread.Sleep/Invoke on new thread. Also, i think one can wrap multiple calls to `Control.Invoke` in single try/catch and catch any exceptions thrown on UI thread just fine.

Comment: @user1747819 Added a C# 3.0 solution.

Comment: @Servy this is will work, but it will keep on repeating itself in time specified, i want the code to exactly run once. that timer only run one time

Comment: @user1747819 That's a pretty trivial modification, but I've made that appropriate edit for you.

Comment: Thank you for this, especially the C# 3.0 version. But I'm thinking it would be better to put the timer.Stop() ahead of the action() method call. And maybe also throw in a timer.Dispose() too?

Comment: @RenniePet It doesn't matter what order you call those two methods in; the same thing will happen either way.  You could dispose of it if you want to, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Put the above code in a background thread, that way it won't block the UI thread. Assuming your methods in between the waits require UI access, they can use Control.BeginInvoke to make an update on the UI thread.

Comment: u mean to say put the whole code with all if statements in a thread?

Comment: But this is then blocking a thread for an extended period of time, which is needlessly wasting resources as opposed to executing the code asynchronously.

Comment: Yes - run everything in a separate thread (started using your choice of Task, BackgroundWorker, or Thread). Sleeping and non-UI based code will work asynchronously. Anything that accesses a UI component will throw an exception - so wrap that section in BeginInvoke. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28485/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-5-of-n

Comment: Servy - a sleeping thread blocks that thread but it doesn't spin the CPU, that would be akin to using SpinWait, which I'm not advocating.

Comment: @Deeko I realize that, but just having threads that aren't using the CPU, when they're occupied for an extended period of time, is still consuming system resources.  In particular it doesn't scale.  The OS can only support a given number of threads alive at any one time, so doing this is eating up one of those possible threads.  If you have a lot of delayed actions then this approach isn't possible.  If you use an asynchronous approach it scales much more effectively.

Comment: Certainly true, depending on your application's scaling needs, but as noted in your answer, async gets progressively more difficult the older your version of C# :)

Comment: but if i port the whole code in thread, there are certain functions which i need to call from the code i m porting in thread.

Comment: and same functions are also used by others also

Comment: @Servy - yes indeed.  That would be thousands, and so not relevant to many apps.

Comment: @user1747819 As long as those other methods are instance methods, you can still call them from a background thread. Just make sure you put UI calls in control.BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Currently only the .NET framework 4.5 supports the async-await mechanism.

if you're looking at solution backward compatible you should check out this link on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners).

the Background worker will execute your tasks asynchronously in a separate thread context for long running process, keeping your UI responsiveness,

Hope it helps

Comment: You don't need to be using .NET 4.5 to use asynchronous programming, it just makes it easier.